# HTML5 Video freeze when using css3 animation

Tags: html, css, video, opacity, freeze

I'm playing a full screen html5 video, and try to display some text with opacity animations.
I encoded the video at the minimum for having the best performance, and when I only play it, it's really fluid.
But as soon as I display my text with a simple opacity animation ( from 0 to 1)
the video is freezing.
The text is only composed of 8 paragraphs and I displayed them with a delay.

I'm not sure that this is due to the opacity as I saw an article about this:

> Opacity animations are always accelerated. I've heard some people say
>   opacity transitions and animations are bad for performance. That's not
>   true. Opacity  changes are pushed to the GPU by default, just like 3d
>   transforms. In fact, according to Paul Irish (YouTube link below)
>   opacity is one of the most performant CSS properties.

Someone already go through this problem ?

```
   #video{
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      z-index: -100;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show some code of how you play it fullscreen and still are able to show some text ?

Comment: Ps : requesting fullscreen on the container and setting video's width and height to 100%, I'm not able to reproduce your issue, whatever the transition duration is set to.

Comment: I edited my post, but I think it's due to my config, It work well on my macbook pro, and get choppy on my netbook asus. I tried to encode my video in a low resolution but the netbook don't like the full screen... Can you tell me on which config did you test, and what was the video resolution ?

Comment: FF on macbook pro 2011, 1080p

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **filter to none** on your text CSS class.

> .myText{ filter:none;}